# Retrofit2 doesn't consume endpoint - Spotify API

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I'm trying to use retrofit2 with Observables and Lombok for my models to get a token for the spotify API. I tried with postman and it worked correctly but I have problems with Java. I have these 3 classes:

**AuthorizationServiceCommandImpl.java**

```
import com.service.userservice.feature.authorization.backend.model.Token;
import lombok.NonNull;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import rx.Single;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

@Service
public class AuthorizationServiceCommandImpl implements AuthorizationServiceCommand {


    private AuthorizationService authorizationService;

    private static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient =
                new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        return httpClient.build()
    }

    public void getToken(String code) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(createOkHttpClient())
                .build();

        authorizationService = retrofit.create(AuthorizationService.class);

        // At this point all these attributes have a value, I used System.out.println to confirm:
        // clientId, clientSecret, grantType, code, redirectUri

        authorizationService
                .getToken(clientId, clientSecret, grantType, code, redirectUri)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(token-> token.toString());
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationService.java**

```
import com.service.userservice.feature.authorization.backend.model.Token;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import rx.Single;

public interface AuthorizationService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("token")
    Single<Token> getToken(@Field("client_id") String clientId,
                        @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                        @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                        @Field("code") String code,
                        @Field("redirect_uri") String redirectUri);

}
```

**My Model, Token.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")
public class Token {

    @SerializedName("access_token")
    private String accessToken;

    @SerializedName("token_type")
    private String tokenType;

    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    private String expiresIn;

    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    private String refreshToken;

    @SerializedName("scope")
    private String scope;

    @SerializedName("error_description")
    private String errorDescription;

    @SerializedName("error")
    private String error;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("Token{" +
            "accessToken='" + accessToken + '\'' +
            ", tokenType='" + tokenType + '\'' +
            ", expiresIn='" + expiresIn + '\'' +
            ", refreshToken='" + refreshToken + '\'' +
            ", scope='" + scope + '\'' +
            ", errorDescription='" + errorDescription + '\'' +
            ", error='" + error + '\'' +
            '}');
        return "Token{" +
            "accessToken='" + accessToken + '\'' +
            ", tokenType='" + tokenType + '\'' +
            ", expiresIn='" + expiresIn + '\'' +
            ", refreshToken='" + refreshToken + '\'' +
            ", scope='" + scope + '\'' +
            ", errorDescription='" + errorDescription + '\'' +
            ", error='" + error + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

This line doesn't show anything:

.map(token-> token.toString());

It's like the call was never done. Not sure how I can confirm that the call was done and also I tried to remove these 2 Observables lines

.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())

and return

```
Single<Token> getToken(@Field("client_id") String clientId,
```

but not worked. Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
.map(token->token.toString());
```

does do something: it returns a modified observable. However, the modified observable is then thrown away. An observable has to be subscribed in order to activate it.

It's possible you can get away with adding the operator at the end:

```
.map(token->token.toString())
.subscriber();
```

However, it isn't clear what you want to do with the mapped string.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I didn't want to do anything with the string, I just wanted to show on console if the call was done and if the token model was mapped correctly. Thanks for your help